# Bottom modal box impossible to close if content is too tall

Tags: javascript, html, css

I need to add to my site a modal box like [this w3school example](https://www.w3schools.com/howto/tryit.asp?filename=tryhow_css_modal_bottom).

Everything works fine, except when the content of the modal becomes very "tall" (e.g. many rows to diplay).

I've been trying inserting `overflow:auto` here and there to hopefully make it scrollable, but I had no success and the modal can't be closed when this happens.

I guess one way to go would be to set a constrain to the `modal-content` top when the content gets too tall, to make it stick to the top of the page, but I sincerely don't know how.

Here is a bit of code to give you an idea of my problem:

```js
// Get the modal
var modal = document.getElementById('myModal');

// Get the button that opens the modal
var btn = document.getElementById("myBtn");

// Get the <span> element that closes the modal
var span = document.getElementsByClassName("close")[0];

// When the user clicks the button, open the modal 
btn.onclick = function() {
    modal.style.display = "block";
}

// When the user clicks on <span> (x), close the modal
span.onclick = function() {
    modal.style.display = "none";
}

// When the user clicks anywhere outside of the modal, close it
window.onclick = function(event) {
    if (event.target == modal) {
        modal.style.display = "none";
    }
}
```

```css
body {font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;}

/* The Modal (background) */
.modal {
    display: none; /* Hidden by default */
    position: fixed; /* Stay in place */
    z-index: 1; /* Sit on top */
    left: 0;
    top: 0;
    width: 100%; /* Full width */
    height: 100%; /* Full height */
    overflow: auto; /* Enable scroll if needed */
    background-color: rgb(0,0,0); /* Fallback color */
    background-color: rgba(0,0,0,0.4); /* Black w/ opacity */
    -webkit-animation-name: fadeIn; /* Fade in the background */
    -webkit-animation-duration: 0.4s;
    animation-name: fadeIn;
    animation-duration: 0.4s
}

/* Modal Content */
.modal-content {
    position: fixed;
    bottom: 0;
    background-color: #fefefe;
    width: 100%;
    -webkit-animation-name: slideIn;
    -webkit-animation-duration: 0.4s;
    animation-name: slideIn;
    animation-duration: 0.4s
}

/* The Close Button */
.close {
    color: white;
    float: right;
    font-size: 28px;
    font-weight: bold;
}

.close:hover,
.close:focus {
    color: #000;
    text-decoration: none;
    cursor: pointer;
}

.modal-header {
    padding: 2px 16px;
    background-color: #5cb85c;
    color: white;
}

.modal-body {padding: 2px 16px;}

.modal-footer {
    padding: 2px 16px;
    background-color: #5cb85c;
    color: white;
}

/* Add Animation */
@-webkit-keyframes slideIn {
    from {bottom: -300px; opacity: 0} 
    to {bottom: 0; opacity: 1}
}

@keyframes slideIn {
    from {bottom: -300px; opacity: 0}
    to {bottom: 0; opacity: 1}
}

@-webkit-keyframes fadeIn {
    from {opacity: 0} 
    to {opacity: 1}
}

@keyframes fadeIn {
    from {opacity: 0} 
    to {opacity: 1}
}
```

```html
<h2>Bottom Modal</h2>

<!-- Trigger/Open The Modal -->
<button id="myBtn">Open Modal</button>

<!-- The Modal -->
<div id="myModal" class="modal">

  <!-- Modal content -->
  <div class="modal-content">
    <div class="modal-header">
      <span class="close">&times;</span>
      <h2>Modal Header</h2>
    </div>
    <div class="modal-body">
      <p>Some text in the Modal Body</p>
      <p>Some other text...</p>
      <p>Some text in the Modal Body</p>
      <p>Some other text...</p>
      <p>Some text in the Modal Body</p>
      <p>Some other text...</p>
      <p>Some text in the Modal Body</p>
      <p>Some other text...</p>
      <p>Some text in the Modal Body</p>
      <p>Some other text...</p>
      <p>Some text in the Modal Body</p>
      <p>Some other text...</p>
      <p>Some text in the Modal Body</p>
      <p>Some other text...</p>
      <p>Some text in the Modal Body</p>
      <p>Some other text...</p>
      <p>Some text in the Modal Body</p>
      <p>Some other text...</p>
      <p>Some text in the Modal Body</p>
      <p>Some other text...</p>
      <p>Some text in the Modal Body</p>
      <p>Some other text...</p>
      <p>Some text in the Modal Body</p>
      <p>Some other text...</p>
      <p>Some text in the Modal Body</p>
      <p>Some other text...</p>
      <p>Some text in the Modal Body</p>
      <p>Some other text...</p>
      <p>Some text in the Modal Body</p>
      <p>Some other text...</p>
      <p>Some text in the Modal Body</p>
      <p>Some other text...</p>
    </div>
    <div class="modal-footer">
      <h3>Modal Footer</h3>
    </div>
  </div>

</div>
```

**EDIT**

Just a quick update: I finally ended up using the [amazing CSS `flexbox`es](https://www.w3schools.com/css/css3_flexbox.asp) and my code works much better now and looks like this:

```js
// Get the modal
var modal = document.getElementById('myModal');

// Get the button that opens the modal
var btn = document.getElementById("myBtn");

// Get the <span> element that closes the modal
var span = document.getElementsByClassName("close")[0];

// When the user clicks the button, open the modal 
btn.onclick = function() {
    modal.style.display = "flex";
}

// When the user clicks on <span> (x), close the modal
span.onclick = function() {
    modal.style.display = "none";
}

// When the user clicks anywhere outside of the modal, close it
window.onclick = function(event) {
    if (event.target == modal) {
        modal.style.display = "none";
    }
}
```

```css
body {font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;}

/* The Modal (background) */
.modal {
    display: none; /* Hidden by default */
    position: fixed; /* Stay in place */
    z-index: 1; /* Sit on top */
    left: 0;
    top: 0;
    width: 100%; /* Full width */
    height: 100%; /* Full height */
    background-color: rgb(0,0,0); /* Fallback color */
    background-color: rgba(0,0,0,0.4); /* Black w/ opacity */
    -webkit-animation-name: fadeIn; /* Fade in the background */
    -webkit-animation-duration: 0.4s;
    animation-name: fadeIn;
    animation-duration: 0.4s
}

/* Modal Content */
.modal-content {
    background-color: #fefefe;
    width: 100%;
    display:flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    margin-top: auto;
    -webkit-animation-name: slideIn;
    -webkit-animation-duration: 0.4s;
    animation-name: slideIn;
    animation-duration: 0.4s
}

/* The Close Button */
.close {
    color: white;
    float: right;
    font-size: 28px;
    font-weight: bold;
}

.close:hover,
.close:focus {
    color: #000;
    text-decoration: none;
    cursor: pointer;
}

.modal-header {
    padding: 2px 16px;
    background-color: #5cb85c;
    color: white;
}

.modal-body {
    padding: 16px 16px;
    max-height:250px;
    overflow: auto; /* Enable scroll if needed *
}

.modal-footer {
    padding: 2px 16px;
    background-color: #5cb85c;
    color: white;
}

/* Add Animation */
@-webkit-keyframes slideIn {
    from {bottom: -300px; opacity: 0} 
    to {bottom: 0; opacity: 1}
}

@keyframes slideIn {
    from {bottom: -300px; opacity: 0}
    to {bottom: 0; opacity: 1}
}

@-webkit-keyframes fadeIn {
    from {opacity: 0} 
    to {opacity: 1}
}

@keyframes fadeIn {
    from {opacity: 0} 
    to {opacity: 1}
}
```

```html
<h2>Bottom Modal</h2>

<!-- Trigger/Open The Modal -->
<button id="myBtn">Open Modal</button>

<!-- The Modal -->
<div id="myModal" class="modal">

  <!-- Modal content -->
  <div class="modal-content">
    <div class="modal-header">
      <span class="close">&times;</span>
      <h2>Modal Header</h2>
    </div>
    <div class="modal-body">
      <p>Some text in the Modal Body</p>
      <p>Some other text...</p>
      <p>Some text in the Modal Body</p>
      <p>Some other text...</p>
      <p>Some text in the Modal Body</p>
      <p>Some other text...</p>
      <p>Some text in the Modal Body</p>
      <p>Some other text...</p>
      <p>Some text in the Modal Body</p>
      <p>Some other text...</p>
      <p>Some text in the Modal Body</p>
      <p>Some other text...</p>
      <p>Some text in the Modal Body</p>
      <p>Some other text...</p>
      <p>Some text in the Modal Body</p>
      <p>Some other text...</p>
      <p>Some text in the Modal Body</p>
      <p>Some other text...</p>
      <p>Some text in the Modal Body</p>
      <p>Some other text...</p>
      <p>Some text in the Modal Body</p>
      <p>Some other text...</p>
      <p>Some text in the Modal Body</p>
      <p>Some other text...</p>
      <p>Some text in the Modal Body</p>
      <p>Some other text...</p>
      <p>Some text in the Modal Body</p>
      <p>Some other text...</p>
      <p>Some text in the Modal Body</p>
      <p>Some other text...</p>
      <p>Some text in the Modal Body</p>
      <p>Some other text...</p>
    </div>
  </div>

</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Update `modal-body` css class as below

```
.modal-body {padding: 2px 16px; height: 250px; overflow: auto}
```

Comment: Thanks. That worked as I needed. Setting the height to a fixed value was definitely the solution!

Comment: Anyway, I used `max-height: 250px;` so that the if the content was short, it will not occupy too much vertical-space full of blank content. Thanks again.

Answer (score 1):

```js
// Get the modal
var modal = document.getElementById('myModal');

// Get the button that opens the modal
var btn = document.getElementById("myBtn");

// Get the <span> element that closes the modal
var span = document.getElementsByClassName("close")[0];

// When the user clicks the button, open the modal 
btn.onclick = function() {
    modal.style.display = "block";
}

// When the user clicks on <span> (x), close the modal
span.onclick = function() {
    modal.style.display = "none";
}

// When the user clicks anywhere outside of the modal, close it
window.onclick = function(event) {
    if (event.target == modal) {
        modal.style.display = "none";
    }
}
```

```css
body {font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;}

/* The Modal (background) */
.modal {
    display: none; /* Hidden by default */
    position: fixed; /* Stay in place */
    z-index: 1; /* Sit on top */
    left: 0;
    top: 0;
    width: 100%; /* Full width */
    height: 100%; /* Full height */
    overflow: auto; /* Enable scroll if needed */
    background-color: rgb(0,0,0); /* Fallback color */
    background-color: rgba(0,0,0,0.4); /* Black w/ opacity */
    -webkit-animation-name: fadeIn; /* Fade in the background */
    -webkit-animation-duration: 0.4s;
    animation-name: fadeIn;
    animation-duration: 0.4s
}

/* Modal Content */
.modal-content {
    position:relative;
    bottom: 0;
    background-color: #fefefe;
    width: 100%;
    -webkit-animation-name: slideIn;
    -webkit-animation-duration: 0.4s;
    animation-name: slideIn;
    animation-duration: 0.4s
}

/* The Close Button */
.close {
    color: white;
    float: right;
    font-size: 28px;
    font-weight: bold;
}

.close:hover,
.close:focus {
    color: #000;
    text-decoration: none;
    cursor: pointer;
}

.modal-header {
    padding: 2px 16px;
    background-color: #5cb85c;
    color: white;
}

.modal-body {padding: 2px 16px;}

.modal-footer {
    padding: 2px 16px;
    background-color: #5cb85c;
    color: white;
}

/* Add Animation */
@-webkit-keyframes slideIn {
    from {bottom: -300px; opacity: 0} 
    to {bottom: 0; opacity: 1}
}

@keyframes slideIn {
    from {bottom: -300px; opacity: 0}
    to {bottom: 0; opacity: 1}
}

@-webkit-keyframes fadeIn {
    from {opacity: 0} 
    to {opacity: 1}
}

@keyframes fadeIn {
    from {opacity: 0} 
    to {opacity: 1}
}
```

```html
<h2>Bottom Modal</h2>

<!-- Trigger/Open The Modal -->
<button id="myBtn">Open Modal</button>

<!-- The Modal -->
<div id="myModal" class="modal">

  <!-- Modal content -->
  <div class="modal-content">
    <div class="modal-header">
      <span class="close">&times;</span>
      <h2>Modal Header</h2>
    </div>
    <div class="modal-body">
      <p>Some text in the Modal Body</p>
      <p>Some other text...</p>
      <p>Some text in the Modal Body</p>
      <p>Some other text...</p>
      <p>Some text in the Modal Body</p>
      <p>Some other text...</p>
      <p>Some text in the Modal Body</p>
      <p>Some other text...</p>
      <p>Some text in the Modal Body</p>
      <p>Some other text...</p>
      <p>Some text in the Modal Body</p>
      <p>Some other text...</p>
      <p>Some text in the Modal Body</p>
      <p>Some other text...</p>
      <p>Some text in the Modal Body</p>
      <p>Some other text...</p>
      <p>Some text in the Modal Body</p>
      <p>Some other text...</p>
      <p>Some text in the Modal Body</p>
      <p>Some other text...</p>
      <p>Some text in the Modal Body</p>
      <p>Some other text...</p>
      <p>Some text in the Modal Body</p>
      <p>Some other text...</p>
      <p>Some text in the Modal Body</p>
      <p>Some other text...</p>
      <p>Some text in the Modal Body</p>
      <p>Some other text...</p>
      <p>Some text in the Modal Body</p>
      <p>Some other text...</p>
      <p>Some text in the Modal Body</p>
      <p>Some other text...</p>
    </div>
    <div class="modal-footer">
      <h3>Modal Footer</h3>
    </div>
  </div>

</div>
```

Just add a pinch of css and you're done...

```
.modal-content {
    position:relative;
}
```

Note: This will allow scrollbar if the content is larger than screen height.

Comment: This is nice, but the modal does not get stick to the bottom anymore this way (you will understand if you lolok at [the original example](https://www.w3schools.com/howto/tryit.asp?filename=tryhow_css_modal_bottom) where the content is not as "tall" as mine).

Comment: It is because the content is larger than screen height, If you keep the content less that screen height then it will be perfect.

Comment: No, the main problem is that the modal is supposed to be a "bottom" modal. With `.modal-content{position:relative;}` it sticks to the top, and this is seen especially when content is not tall (as I said, see the example I linked to and try changing what you proposed there to understand the problem).

Answer (score -1):

Where did you put the overflow?
I tried adding **overflow-x: scroll;** on **.modal-content**. 
It works on my side and the modal closes normally. just adjust height, top or whatever position you would like, if this works for you too.

cheers.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback. Anyway, the problem is the height so I guess it would be more overflow-y than overflow-x. However, I did insert it in .modal-content but I just get a grey scroll-bar which does not let me scroll, and I cannot close the modal as the close button (or the window behind the modal) are not visible/accessible. If you did solve it, can you please provide the code snippet you tried or something I can test?